# Defining abstract interface methods

Tags: java

If you create an abstract child of an abstract parent that implements an interface do you need to define the abstract interface methods in that child?

if I can get an example of this in code that would be helpful thank you!

Comment: Why not try it?

Answer (score 1):

No. When your child class is abstract, you **don't** need to implement the abstract methods of the parent.

Since your child is abstract, it can't be instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

***Short answer: No.***

**Long answer like the ones your lecturer (or mine) would give you:**

Assume we have an interface, `AbstInter` with some functions:

```
public interface AbstInter {
    void funct1();

    String funct2();
}
```

And then a class that implements it:

```
public abstract class AbstParent implements AbstInter {
    public int funct3() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And a child class that extends the previous class:

```
public abstract class AbstChild extends AbstParent {
    // nothing here for now
}
```

The IDE would not give me any errors.

Comment: But `AbstChild` isn't abstract.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed now! @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica